# Less nested rules - can i put the cascaded selector before the main selector?

Tags: css, nested, less

My selector needs to be:

```css
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow
```

So I use the following nested rule:

```css
.tooltip-arrow {
  .tooltip.right {
     left: -(@ttArrowSize - 5);
     margin-top: -@ttArrowSize;
     border-width: @ttArrowSize @ttArrowSize @ttArrowSize 0;
     border-right-color: @ttColor;
  }
}
```

But after compiling the selector looks like:

```css
.tooltip-arrow .tooltip.right
```

The main question is if I can indicate LESS to put the "cascaded" selector before the main one. Any workarounds are welcome as well.

Comment: Add the parent selector `&` after `.tooltip.right` :)

Comment: You mean like this? .tooltip.right{ .tooltip-arrow{ //something } } If yes it's not the case because i have tooltip.left and tooltip.bottom and tooltip.top as well. The point is to have something like .tooltip{ .left{} .rigth{} .top{} .bottom{} }

Comment: If you really want to add nesting like `.tooltip { .left{} .right{}..}` (as indicated in above comment) then something like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNMMmV) would help you.

Comment: Paulie nailed it (see the selected answer)

Comment: Not disputing the answer mate. I wanted to give an option just in case the structure needs to be as in that comment. That structure is slightly different from Paulie's answer :) If I really have to recommend an approach, I would recommend the same approach as in Paulie's answer only.

Comment: Just two words: [The Docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature-changing-selector-order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ampersand selector, which refers to the parent selector inside a nested selector.

[**Interesting Article**](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-29/less-css-secrets-of-the-ampersand/)

So this in LESS

```
.tooltip-arrow {    
    .tooltip.right & {
            color:red;
    }      
    .tooltip.left & {
            color:blue;
    }
}
```

compiles to this in CSS

```
.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
  color: red;
}
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
  color: blue;
}
```